# Simple Process workflow on Android

Tags: android

I want to run a very 4 simple process,every process have an interval time I'm using `CountDownTimer`to run the first process with a specified interval when it finish then run the second one, and third one until the last one, as you can what the process should do it's make a circle progress  visible.
The code below works for the first call of the method`StartProcess(30000,1)` if I put it alone, but does not work I want to run the process four time:

```
StartProcess(30000,1);//Run progress bar on imageButton1
StartProcess(40000,2);//Run progress bar on imageButton2
StartProcess(50000,3);//Run progress bar on imageButton3
StartProcess(60000,4);//Run progress bar on imageButton4
```

Only the four process run, I know there is wait to archive this, so far I can find it, can you please help.

See Images:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzg0AQsGg3kkWGpEa3pGX3R6S0k/view?usp=sharing

This code from MainActivity

```
package com.example.WaterProcess;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progress1,progress2,progress3,progress4;
    ImageView img_Backwash, img_BrineSlot,img_BrineRefill,img_FastRinse;
    TextView txt_timer;
     public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";



    public  int nProcessID=0;
    public boolean bProcessStop=false;

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        img_Backwash=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_backwash);
        img_BrineSlot =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_brine_slow);
        img_BrineRefill=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_brine_refill);
        img_FastRinse=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_fast_rinse);

        progress1 =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel1);
        progress2 =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel2);
        progress3 =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel3);
        progress4 =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel4);

        progress1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progress2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progress3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progress4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        txt_timer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_timer);







        btn_Start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bnt_start);
        btn_Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override[enter image description here][1]
            public void onClick(View view) {

                StartProcess(30000,1);//Run progress bar on imageButton1
                StartProcess(40000,2);//Run progress bar on imageButton2
                StartProcess(50000,3);//Run progress bar on imageButton3
                StartProcess(60000,4);//Run progress bar on imageButton4


            }
        });




    }

    public void StartProcess(long Interval,int ProcessID) {

            this.nProcessID=ProcessID;

          //  for (int nCount = 1; nCount<= 4; nCount++) {

              //  Log.d("Conteo en FOR", Integer.toString(nCount));

                new CountDownTimer(Interval, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        txt_timer.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
                        UpdateProcess(nProcessID,true);//Los Progress
                        Log.d("Conteo en Segundos", Long.toString(millisUntilFinished));
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                          txt_timer.setText("Done");
                          UpdateProcess(nProcessID);

                    }
                }.start();

            //}
          //  Log.d("Conteo------->", "Fin del Conteo");


    }


    void UpdateProcess(int ProcessNumber){

      progress4 =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel4);


        switch (ProcessNumber){
            case 1:
                img_Backwash.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_complete);
                progress1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nProcessID=0;

                break;
            case 2:
                img_BrineSlot.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_complete);
                progress2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nProcessID=0;

                break;
            case 3:
                img_BrineRefill.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_complete);
                progress3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nProcessID=0;

                break;
            case 4:
                img_FastRinse.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_complete);
                progress4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nProcessID=0;


                break;
        }
    }


    void UpdateProcess(int ProcessNumber,boolean IsProgressBar){


        switch (ProcessNumber){

            case 1:

                progress1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 2:

                progress2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 3:

                progress3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 4:

                progress4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated in your question (I'm using CountDownTimerto run the first process with a specified interval when it finish then run the second one, and third one until the last one). If I understand you want to execute the tasks one after the other in a sequential manner

But You are using a CountDownTimer class for each of your request and hence all the request will start simultaneously. In order to start new task after the previous one finishes you need to call next task on you previous task's finish method. Below is a sample code that you can use.

```
    public void StartProcess(long Interval,int ProcessID) {
            this.nProcessID=ProcessID;

                new CountDownTimer(Interval, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        txt_timer.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
                        UpdateProcess(nProcessID,true);//Los Progress
                        Log.d("Conteo en Segundos", Long.toString(millisUntilFinished));
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                          txt_timer.setText("Done");
                          UpdateProcess(nProcessID);
                          if(null != listener) {
                             listener.onTaskComplete(nProcessID);
                          }
                    }
                }.start();

            //}
          //  Log.d("Conteo------->", "Fin del Conteo");
    }

public static interface TaskCompletedListener {
      public void onTaskComplete(int processId);
}

private class TaskListener implements TaskCompletedListener {
     public void onTaskComplete(int processId) {
       switch(processId) {
        case 1:
        break;
          StartProcess(40000,2);
        case 2:
          StartProcess(50000,3)
        break;
        case 3:
          StartProcess(60000,4);
        break;
       }
     }
}
```

And in your onclick event do like this

```
btn_Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override[enter image description here][1]
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StartProcess(30000,1);//Run progress bar on imageButton1
            }
        });
```

Note: the listener object is an instance of TaskListener which you need to create declare at class level at instantiate it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did as you suggested by only the first process execute OK, the others ones are not working.

Comment: listerner it's always null

 if(null != listener) {
                            Log.d("Conteo en onFinish", "ProcessID "+Integer.toString(nProcessID));
                            listener.onTaskComplete(nProcessID);

Comment: Now it's working properly I forgot to instance the TaskListener as you said.
Thanks a lot @ayaanp